# Full text search - keyword to keyword (input field>database column)

Tags: mysql, pdo, full-text-search

Can anyone help me get my desired code?
I have an input field, where multiple keywords will be written.
Example:

```
opel corsa car
```

I have tag entries in my database, separated by comma:

```
1. opel, corsa
2. car, opel
3. juice
4. car
```

What I want to do is, implement full text search, but based on keyword to keyword search, meaning that I want to list out all the results containing any of the keywords.
However I want to trim those search words by 2 letters, in case someone searches for corsoa, or corsae instead of corsa.

What I got so far is:

```
$input = $_GET["tag"];
$input = mb_strtolower($input,'UTF-8');
$tag = explode(" ", $input);
$tagCheck = '(tags LIKE "%'.implode('%") OR (tags LIKE "%', $tag).'%")';
```

and in query

```
$dbq = $dbco->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE ".$tagCheck." HAVING MAX(price) < 50000");
```

Comment: note: if someone types in "opel corsa" i don't want "car, opel" to get listed out...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change your Db design (if you can).

Try to create a database relational to take advance of the performance beside to make queries 'more simply'.

in your query try with the function find_in_set of MySQL.

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', field)
```

Example:

```
mysql> select * from fruits;
+-------------------------------+
| fruit                         |
+-------------------------------+
| banana, apple, orange, grapes |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from fruits where find_in_set(' apple',fruit);
+-------------------------------+
| fruit                         |
+-------------------------------+
| banana, apple, orange, grapes |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

if your table is MyISAM or Innodb (with MySQL V. 5.6.+) you can create text index and make queries with like

in your select, use this

```
 SELECT ... WHERE tads like ('%text%')
```

use % (wildcards)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think that would cover my problem. What if someone searches for "apple oranges". wouldn't this idea stop once "apple" is found? and what if someone mistypes "orang"?
Btw. exact database doesn't deal with cars and groups of them. It has a variety of products, which would be hard to categorize...

Comment: @user1460744 Try to create a Entity Relationship model, it will be A LOT better for your performance, scalability, queries, etc... like you have it right now you are not even using the Index how you suppose to.